# PHPunit тест для функции

Tags: php, phpunit

Есть функция f(), не принимающая параметров и содержащая другие функции f1, f2, f3, f4, expect. Другие функции (f1, f2, f3, f4, expect) описаны в подключаемом файле. Функция f2 - записывает данные в БД. Функция expect - считывает данные из БД.
Стоит задача проверить, что данные, предназначенные для записи в БД ($p), равны данным, которые считаются из БД.

```
require_once (<файл с подключаемыми функциями>);    
function f() {
    global $v;
    $v->method();
    $p = $v->method2();
    $p['key1'] = f1();
    $p['key2'] = strlen($p['key2']);
    f2 ($p);
    f3();
    f4();
}
```

Есть файл с кодом теста PHPunit

```
/**
 * @dataProvider pProvider
 */
public function test_f($p) {
// что-то надо добавить
    f();
    $exp = expect();
    $this->assertEquals($p, $exp);
}

public function pProvider()
{
    return array (
        array('string1'),
        array('string12'),
        array('string123'),
        array('string1234')
    );
}
```

Вопросы:

1. как передать данные из провайдера в тестируемую функцию? Ведь в
   исходной функции f() переменная p является внутренней

   2. что делать с функциями f1, f2, f3, f4 внутри тестируемой функции f?
   3. что делать с глобальной переменной и её свойствами ( global $v и $v->method())?

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что нужно сделать - избавиться от `global`. Тут и везде по своему проекту. Никогда, нигде ни при каких обстоятельствах не используйте `global`. Это явный признак плохой архитектуры. Так называемый "запах" кода.

Для выполнения первого пункта почитайте про [DI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). Это как раз про вынесение `$v` наружу и передачи её внутрь функции в качестве аргумента. Таким же аргументом будет и ваша `$p`.

После этого у вас уже не будет проблем с передачей контекста внутрь тестируемой функции.

Функции внутри тестируемой лучше [мокать](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82), а не использовать оригинальные версии. Т.к. сейчас получается, что вы тестируете базу данных, а не саму функцию. Если тест именно юнит, а не компонентный/функциональный/UI, то нет смысла тестировать всё совокупно. Напишите тесты отдельно для каждой функции, для каждой атомарной неделимой части вашего кода. А обвязку над всеми функциями отложите на потом, - это тест другого уровня.

Comment: Насчёт использования global я в курсе, что это плохо. Но, увы - платформа, на которой нужно запустить phpunit тест, написана именно так. И даже если вынести $p = $v->method2();за пределы функции, то полученную переменную $p мне придётся передавать в качестве параметра в тестируемую функцию, меняя её сигнатуру.